# How to rotate old log files in a unique file.tar.gz?

Tags: rhel, logrotate

How can I rotate all the log files older 30 days in a unique file.tar.gz and remove the files inserted in the archive?

Before:

```
a.log // older than 30days
b.log // older than 30days
c.log // older than 20 days
```

After:

```
backup.tgz
c.log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
find . -name '*log' -mtime +30 -print0 | tar -czvf backup.tgz --remove-files --null -T -
```

With:

- `find` options:

  - `-name '*log' -mtime +30`: selects log files older than 30 days
  - `-print0`: print  the  full  file  name on the standard output,  followed by a null character
- `tar` options:

  - `--remove-files`: remove files after adding them to the archive
  - `--null`: reads null-terminated names (sent by `find -print0`)
  - `-T -`: reads filenames from stdin (`find`'s output)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the Linux logger and you can add a rotation config to the [/etc/logrotate.d](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html) directory in which you can specify the size, and format, etc...

Example:

```
/var/log/test.log {
    rotate 30
    weekly
    size=30k
    compress 
}
```

Here is a [cheat sheet](https://www.jamescoyle.net/cheat-sheets/676-logrotate-cheat-sheet) for the scripts.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but is this method i don't have a unique file compress, but many single compress file for any log. I've need that every log is compress in unique tar for all.